# Creating reverse tunnel with LibSSH

Tags: c, libssh

I have created a simple server and client with following code:

**Client**

```
int main() {
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    int rc;
    char* password;

    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    int port = 900;
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "10.0.0.7");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "user");
    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);

    if (verify_knownhost(my_ssh_session) < 0) {
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-2);
    }

    password = "password";
    rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, password);

    ssh_channel channel;
    channel = ssh_channel_new(my_ssh_session);
    if (channel == NULL)
        return SSH_ERROR;

    rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);
    if (rc != SSH_OK) {
        ssh_channel_free(channel);
        return rc;
    }

    rc = ssh_channel_request_pty(channel);
    if (rc != SSH_OK) return rc;

    rc = ssh_channel_change_pty_size(channel, 80, 24);
    if (rc != SSH_OK) return rc;

    rc = ssh_channel_request_shell(channel);
    if (rc != SSH_OK) return rc;

    char buffer[256];
    int nbytes, nwritten;

    while (ssh_channel_is_open(channel) && !ssh_channel_is_eof(channel)) {
        if (!kbhit()) {
            Sleep(100); // 0.05 second
        }
        nbytes = ssh_channel_read_nonblocking(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (nbytes < 0) return SSH_ERROR;
        if (nbytes > 0) {
            nwritten = write(1, buffer, nbytes);
            if (nwritten != nbytes) return SSH_ERROR;
            continue;
        }

        nbytes = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (nbytes < 0) return SSH_ERROR;
        if (nbytes > 0) {
            nwritten = ssh_channel_write(channel, buffer, nbytes);
            if (nwritten != nbytes) return SSH_ERROR;
        }
    }

    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);
    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

**Server**

```
static int main_loop(ssh_channel chan) {
    ssh_session session = ssh_channel_get_session(chan);
    socket_t fd;
    struct termios *term = NULL;
    struct winsize *win = NULL;
    pid_t childpid;
    ssh_event event;
    short events;


    childpid = forkpty(&fd, NULL, term, win);
    if(childpid == 0) {
        execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", (char *)NULL);
        abort();
    }

    cb.userdata = &fd;
    ssh_callbacks_init(&cb);
    ssh_set_channel_callbacks(chan, &cb);

    events = POLLIN | POLLPRI | POLLERR | POLLHUP | POLLNVAL;

    event = ssh_event_new();
    if(event == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't get a event\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(ssh_event_add_fd(event, fd, events, copy_fd_to_chan, chan) != SSH_OK) {
        printf("Couldn't add an fd to the event\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(ssh_event_add_session(event, session) != SSH_OK) {
        printf("Couldn't add the session to the event\n");
        return -1;
    }

    do {
        ssh_event_dopoll(event, 1000);
    } while(!ssh_channel_is_closed(chan));

    ssh_event_remove_fd(event, fd);

    ssh_event_remove_session(event, session);

    ssh_event_free(event);
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    ssh_session session;
    ssh_bind sshbind;
    int port = 900;
    int rc;
    int auth;
    sshbind = ssh_bind_new();
    session=ssh_new();
    //ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_BINDADDR, "localhost");
    ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_BINDPORT, &port);
    ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_HOSTKEY, "ssh-rsa");
    ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_RSAKEY,"/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa");
      
    
    if (ssh_bind_listen(sshbind) < 0) {
        printf("Error listening to socket: %s\n",ssh_get_error(sshbind));
        return -1;
    }
    
    while (1) {
        if (ssh_bind_accept(sshbind, session) == SSH_ERROR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting a connection: `%s'.\n",ssh_get_error(sshbind));
            return -1;
        }
        printf("Accepted a connection.\n");
        
        if (ssh_handle_key_exchange(session)) {
            printf("ssh_handle_key_exchange: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
            return 1;
        }
         

        auth = authenticate(session);
        if (!auth){
            printf("Authentication error: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
            break;
        }
        
        
            
        // wait for a channel session
        ssh_channel channel; 
        ssh_message message;
        do {
        message = ssh_message_get(session);
            if(message){
                if(ssh_message_type(message) == SSH_REQUEST_CHANNEL_OPEN &&
                    ssh_message_subtype(message) == SSH_CHANNEL_SESSION) {
                    channel = ssh_message_channel_request_open_reply_accept(message);
                    ssh_message_free(message);
                    break;
                } else {
                    ssh_message_reply_default(message);
                    ssh_message_free(message);
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while(!channel);
        
        if(!channel) {
            printf("Error: client did not ask for a channel session (%s)\n", ssh_get_error(session));
            ssh_finalize();
            return 1;
        }
        
        // wait for a shell
        int shell = 0;
        do {
            message = ssh_message_get(session);
            if(message != NULL) {
                if(ssh_message_type(message) == SSH_REQUEST_CHANNEL) {
                    if(ssh_message_subtype(message) == SSH_CHANNEL_REQUEST_SHELL) {
                        shell = 1;
                        ssh_message_channel_request_reply_success(message);
                        ssh_message_free(message);
                        break;
                    } else if (ssh_message_subtype(message) == SSH_CHANNEL_REQUEST_PTY) {
                        ssh_message_channel_request_reply_success(message);
                        ssh_message_free(message);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                ssh_message_reply_default(message);
                ssh_message_free(message);
            } else {
            break;
            }
        } while(!shell);

        if(!shell) {
        printf("Error: No shell requested (%s)\n", ssh_get_error(session));
        return 1;
        }
        
        main_loop(channel);

    }
    
    ssh_disconnect(session);
    ssh_bind_free(sshbind);
    ssh_finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I left out some functions to not blow up the code sample.

This example works perfectly fine to receive a shell on my server. However I want to create a reverse tunnel where I can control my client from the server side.
I already tried using the code from the example (https://api.libssh.org/stable/libssh_tutor_forwarding.html) but it did not suceed.

Can anybody tell me how I can shift the control to control the client instead of the server?

EDIT:
If I add following code to my client:

```
rc = ssh_channel_listen_forward(my_ssh_session, NULL, 8080, NULL);
    if (rc != SSH_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening remote port: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        return rc;
    }
```

the ssh_channel_listen_forward never returns.

Comment: That tutorial doesn't seem to include anything about the server side. You might want to take a look at their example code for [direct TCP forwarding](https://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git/tree/examples/sshd_direct-tcpip.c), which doesn't quite do what you want, but is related. I haven't looked through the details but you'll likely need to use `ssh_channel_open_reverse_forward` on the server when a connection is accepted. I didn't find a specific example of it being used there.